# Return to specific locale based on cookie?

Tags: localization, htaccess

If we are storing a cookie of a locale the user choose, is there a way to detect that cookie in htaccess so the next time they visit the base url of the site it will take them to the same locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Storing the cookie

I'd recommend using the [LJ Cookies plugin](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies)...

```
{% do craft.lj_cookies.set('locale', craft.locale, '', '/' ) %}
```

### Retrieving the cookie

The LJ Cookies plugin is also capable of reading cookies, so you could simply put a conditional redirect at the top of your layout...

```
{% set currentLocale = craft.locale %}
{% set goToLocale = craft.lj_cookies.get('locale') %}

{% if goToLocale and (currentLocale != goToLocale %}
    {% redirect '/' ~ goToLocale %}
{% endif %}
```

If you insist on performing the locale redirect at the .htaccess level, that's also possible. It would provide you a small performance improvement, but may not be worth bypassing the simplicity of using LJ Cookies in your template.

Using .htaccess to perform a redirect based on a cookie value is beyond my expertise, and somewhat beyond the scope of the Craft SE site. But I did some quick Googling around for "cookie" and "htaccess", and found a few helpful links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value
- http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#Get_Cookie_Value