# How to set cookie and redirect to page one time

Tags: redirect, member

How can I redirect a member to account page on first visit with a cookie set? My redirect is looping now.

```
{% if currentUser %}
   {% set name = currentUser.firstName %}
   {% do craft.lj_cookies.set('account', name) %}



   {% set redirect = craft.lj_cookies.get('account') %}

   {% if redirect == name %}
       {% redirect name %}
   {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

It's not possible to visit any other URL anymore.

Comment: You want to always redirect a user if they have a particular cookie value set?

Comment: The redirect to the account is just an example. In my case i'm working on a kind of webshop. My members need to fill in there gender. If they enter the site I want them to redirect to the shop with male (shop/male of shop/female) product. After the redirect is up to the member where to go next. Could me male products etc. So just 1 time redirect.

Comment: It's based on this anser: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/return-to-specific-locale-based-on-cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {% set name = currentUser.firstName %}
    {% if craft.lj_cookies.get('account') != name %}
        {% do craft.lj_cookies.set('account', name) %}
        {% redirect name %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

In you're original code you're setting the cookie before getting it into the redirect variable, so the {% if redirect == name %} conditional is always true.

Comment: It's not working. So the cookie only needs to work on the homepage.

Comment: So, this code is in your homepage template (not your layout)? And you want to redirect to /male or /female (as per your comment above) depending on the users gender? Can you access these url's directly when a) you're logged in or b) you're not logged in?

Comment: Yes its on the homepage. So after first visit the redirect gets me to the right page. But if I want to go back to the homepage there is the redirect again.

So just one time a redirect. After that its up to the member.

Comment: Ah, now I get it... Yes, that would be the case. Let me update my answer.